# iOS PageView help. Button actions vs. button creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

So I hired someone on freelancer to build me a pageview, and it looked like what I wanted, but now Idk how to configure the code. Can anyone just tell me where the buttons are being built and where the actions to each button are?

ViewController.m

```
- (ColorViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (([colorsArray count] == 0) || (index >= [colorsArray count])) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSArray *arr = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:index];
    ColorViewController *dataViewController =[[ColorViewController alloc] initWithColorsArray:arr];
    dataViewController.delegate = self;
    return dataViewController;
}


- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(ColorViewController *)viewController
{
    int index = [self indexOfViewController:viewController];
    pagecontrol.currentPage = index;
    if(index == 0){
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index-1];
}
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(ColorViewController *)viewController
{
    int index = [self indexOfViewController:viewController];
    pagecontrol.currentPage = index;
    if(index >= [colorsArray count]-1){
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index+1];
}
- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(ColorViewController *)viewController {
    return [colorsArray indexOfObject:viewController.colorsArray];
}
-(void) pageChanged:(id) sender
{

}
-(void) setColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    [myLabel setTextColor:color];
    _fontColorView.hidden = YES;
}
-(void) setupColorViewControllers
{
    NSDictionary *options =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin]
                                                       forKey: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];

    pagevc = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:options];
    pagevc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 414, 320, 200);
    pagevc.delegate = self;
    pagevc.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:pagevc.view];
    NSArray *c1arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],
                      [UIColor blackColor],
                      [UIColor grayColor],
                      [UIColor blueColor],
                      [UIColor redColor],
                      [UIColor darkGrayColor],
                      [UIColor yellowColor],
                      [UIColor purpleColor],
                      [UIColor greenColor],
                      nil];
    ColorViewController *c1 = [[ColorViewController alloc] initWithColorsArray:c1arr];
    c1.delegate = self;
    NSArray *c2arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor whiteColor],
                      [UIColor redColor],
                      [UIColor blackColor],
                      [UIColor grayColor],
                      [UIColor darkGrayColor],
                      [UIColor purpleColor],
                      [UIColor yellowColor],
                      [UIColor blueColor],
                      [UIColor greenColor],
                      nil];
    NSArray *c3arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [UIColor greenColor],
                      [UIColor blackColor],
                      [UIColor darkGrayColor],
                      [UIColor grayColor],
                      [UIColor whiteColor],

                      [UIColor purpleColor],
                      [UIColor yellowColor],
                      [UIColor blueColor],

                      [UIColor redColor],
                      nil];

    colorsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:c1arr, c2arr, c3arr, nil];
    colorsViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:c1, nil];
    pagecontrol = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 150, 80, 30)];
    pagecontrol.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    [pagecontrol setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.8 blue:0.8 alpha:0.8]];
    [pagecontrol setPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    pagecontrol.numberOfPages = 3;
    pagecontrol.currentPage = 0;
    [pagecontrol addTarget:self action:@selector(pageChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [pagevc.view addSubview:pagecontrol];

    [pagevc setViewControllers:colorsViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        ;
    }];
    pagevc.view.hidden = YES;
    _fontColorView = pagevc.view;
}
```

ColorViewController.m

```
#import "ColorViewController.h"

@interface ColorViewController ()

@end

@implementation ColorViewController

@synthesize colorsArray;
@synthesize delegate;

-(void) setColorsArray:(NSArray*) arr
{
    colorsArray = arr;
    int min = [arr count] > [buttonsArray count] ? [buttonsArray count] : [arr count];
    for(int i = 0; i < min; i++){
        UIColor *color = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton *b = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [b setBackgroundColor:color];
    }
}
-(id) initWithColorsArray:(NSArray*) arr
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        colorsArray = arr;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) color:(id) sender
{
    UIButton *b = (UIButton*) sender;
    [delegate setColor:b.backgroundColor];
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int x = 10, y = 10;
    int size = [colorsArray count] > 10 ? 10 : [colorsArray count];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        UIColor *color = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [b setBackgroundColor:color];
        [b addTarget:self action:@selector(color:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        b.frame = CGRectMake(x , y , 50, 50);
        x += 60;
        if(i == 4){
            y += 60;
            x = 10;
        }
        [buttonsArray addObject:b];
        [self.view addSubview:b];
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons are being instantiated in ViewDidLoad within the ColorViewController class. A button is created for every color in colorsArray

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    UIColor *color = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

and then each of the buttons is given the selector "color:" for the touchUpInside event, meaning that when the button is pressed and released, it will call the method "color" within the same class.

```
[b addTarget:self action:@selector(color:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The "colors:" method checks which button was pressed and then sets the background color of the delegate class to the background color of the button

```
UIButton *b = (UIButton*) sender;
[delegate setColor:b.backgroundColor];
```